# How much energy does it take to magnetize a neodymium magnet?

Tags: energy, magnetic-fields

I read somewhere that when neodymium magnets are made they are subjected to intense magnetic fields in order to magnetize them.

So lets say we have a cubic neodymium magnet that is .5 by .5 by .5 inches in dimension. How much energy would it take to fully magnetize such a magnet when it is being made?

Update : It says [here](https://www.first4magnets.com/tech-centre-i61/information-and-articles-i70/neodymium-magnet-information-i82/how-are-neodymium-magnets-made-i90) that to create a Neodymium magnet they subject the Neodymium alloy to a magnetic field three times the strength of the resulting Neodymium magnet's field via an electromagnet. For how long I do not know, but this means if we can calculate the strength of the Neodymium magnet we can calculate the strength of the electromagnet's magnetic field and possibly calculate the energy used in the electromagnet.

The above does not take into account the energy required to smelt the alloy and other necessary energy, but let's just stick with the magnetization energy.